# Easiest way to replace placeholders (variables) in markdown text?

Tags: markdown, placeholder, pandoc

I have need for an open format to write stories in a generic way (with placeholder/variables). To make the stories case specific I would like to set a list of key/value pairs and apply them when publishing. I also want to separate styling from content so I can easily publish to web, pdf etc.

Example: `@varname@ is a great place.`

I chose Markdown to solve the content/styling separation but I do not know an easy way to parameterize certain parts of the text and have them filled in when I generate the html/pdf outputs with a tool like pandoc.

Any suggestions? Can this be done with markdown or is there a suitable markdown extension?

Comment: Are you also working with a particular programming language? It seems to me that building templates that output Markdown is your best bet, but the details of that approach will depend heavily on your stack.

Comment: @Chris : Not using a particular programming language. I am just looking for an easy to use/configurable key/value solution, e.g. pandoc-extension, to replace certain strings (keys) with corresponding values when publishing the markdown content to any output type (pdf,html,docx).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use something like `sed`, or even `funnelweb`, but you could do it with a pandoc filter, either in haskell or (probably easier) with the `pandocfilters` python library available [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters)

Answer (score 2):

For the web, you could use [Jekyll templates with Liquid](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/). Complex expressions surrounded by double braces `{{}}` are interpreted when converting to HTML. Example (from the link):

> ```
> {{ site.time | date_to_string }}
> ```
>
> 07 Nov 2008

I think it's possible to define custom variables, too.

Comment: best answer I have found to this question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use CSS classes as definitions and HTML tags as placeholders. Just write anywhere in your document a custom style or add it to your renderer:

```
<style>
  area.varname1::after{content: "Berlin";}
  area.varname2::after{content: "Budapest";}
  ...
</style>
```

The `style` block won't be rendered but it will display the `content` of your variables anywhere you use the empty `area` HTML tag with the proper `class` in your document. For example if you write:

```
<area class="varname1"> is a great place.
You should also see <area class="varname2"> one day.
Trains go to <area class="varname2"> from <area class="varname1"> regularly.
```

Will be rendered as:

```
Berlin is a great place.
You should also see Budapest one day.
Trains go to Budapest from Berlin regularly.
```

This trick works if your markdown processor use HTML (a lot does). The `area` tag is great for this purpose as it is widely supported, rarely if ever used in markdown, short and can be empty. The `::after` CSS selector inserts `content` as if it were originally written there, so all markdown formatting should work. For example: `**<area class="varname1">**` should become bold: **Berlin**

This simple solution is bit of a hack for like occasionally used templates, but probably works in any environment with almost all markdown setups out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc's Markdown allows to embed raw LaTeX and even replaces simple definitions, which can be leveraged using a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). E.g.;

```markdown
\def\varname{Berlin}

\varname is a great place.
```

will work right away when producing PDF output.

Below is a Lua filter which makes this trick work for all output formats:

```lua
-- file: tex-macros.lua
function RawInline (r)
  -- Inline expanded TeX commands.
  if r.format == 'tex' and r.text:match '^[^\\]' then
    return pandoc.Str(r.text)
  end
end
```

Use it by passing it via the `--lua-filter` (or `-L`) command line option:

```
pandoc --lua-filter tex-macros.lua ...
```