# Easiest way to replace placeholders (variables) in markdown text using Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I am using Jupyter Notebook. I have a .md file in which I want all the placeholders to be replaced by values defined in another file.

**Theorems.md (the reference file)**

Theorem 1 = theorem blah blah.

**mynotes.md (file where the placeholders should be replaced)**

I like [[Theorems.md_theorem1]]

**mynotes.md preview should be:**

I like theorem blah blah.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499398/easiest-way-to-replace-placeholders-variables-in-markdown-text) answer already. That answer asks something for pandoc. I was wondering if there is some easy way to do this inside jupyter notebook.