# Placeholder variables for text snippets in markdown

Tags: variables, text, replace, markdown, placeholder

I'm trying to write a markdown document that contains something like a centrally specified placeholder variable which allows to propagate a certain text snippet to different locations of the document, e.g.

```
placeholder = markdown files
This is my text about %placeholder%. %placeholder% should be used by everyone.
```

Unfortunately, after some research, I did not found a way to realize this behavior.

I'm aware of the reference-style links functionality of markdown. However, from my point of view, it does not seem to solve exactly the issue I'm facing. Further, https://www.brianchildress.co/variables-in-markdown/ described an approach that perfectly fits to my question. However, the variable `random value` of the provided demo code is not replaced in the text.

I would be glad for any suggestions or at least the hint that the requested feature is not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That blog post is simply wrong. Reference-style links aren't variables, and they don't behave as described there.

One of Markdown's guiding principles is that [files should be readable in their source form](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#philosophy):

> Readability, however, is emphasized above all else. A Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions.

Placeholders conflict with that principle and are not included in Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77910102/23323329) to a similar question easily creates the required behavior using CSS pseudo-elements in HTML-based markdown applications without any add-ons or complicated coding, but degrades the readability of the source form. So, as [Chris pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209495/455269), it also goes against Markdown guiding principles.

It might be possible to create a Markdown add-on for variables that satisfies the guidelines. Such a plugin would would occasionally make sense in some templates:

- For example in **legal documents** sometimes a similar thing is done this way: `Oolong Johnson (hereinafter "Client")` and then, in the document, only `Client` is written everywhere instead of writing out the whole name. This preserves the readability, but readers have to do the
  substitutions in their heads.
- An add-on could do these substitutions. A readable definition and placeholder could be something like
  `[Client]-is: Oolong Johnson` and `[Client]`. At render the
  definition would be hidden and every occurrence of `[Client]` would
  be replaced with `Oolong Johnson`.

This would be as readable as legal documents, which is not great but does the trick, and would work similarly to reference-style links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the sole answer on the entire internet which actually provides this functionality. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a JavaScript variable:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    variable_name = "value"
</script>
```

allows you to reuse those variables elsewhere:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    title = "Document Title"
</script>

# <script>document.write(title)</script>
```

This works in `code-insiders-1.88.0-1710157206.el8`.